# Ler um arquivo .txt em ANSI VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Estou tentando ler um arquivo texto usando visual basic, mas ele coloca "?" nas palavras com acento e cedilha, por exemplo, como faço para ele ler os arquivos no formato  ANSI ?
isto não funciona:

```
Dim ArqTemp As String = File.ReadAllText(Arquivo, Encoding.UTF8)
```

Comment: Tenta trocar o `Encoding.UTF8` para `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(850)`

Comment: Colocou caracteres estanhos ex: "APLICAÃıES "

Comment: Tenta `860` @Aesir

Comment: @Aesir deu certo? O Jéferson deveria colocar como resposta?

Comment: ainda não deu, ficou assim agora: "APLICA╟╒ES"

Comment: Tem certeza que está em `UTF-8`? Tenta como ANSI: `File.ReadAllText(Arquivo, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))`

Comment: Bah verdade cara, assim funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
 Dim ArqTemp As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\acento.txt", Encoding.Default)
```

[image: print]